# How to get the Date of Monday of the next Week in Typoscript?

Tags: date, typo3, typoscript

I 've got some TypoScript like that:

```
lib.kalenderwoche = COA
lib.kalenderwoche {
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    #data = date: U
    #strftime = %d.%m.%Y
    #noTrimWrap = || - |
  }
  20 = TEXT
  20 {
    data = date:U + (7*86400)
    prioriCalc = 1
    strftime = %W
    wrap = |
  }
}
```

But how i calculate the first monday of next week?

Comment: Use `stdWrap.strtotime`, with "next monday" as parameter. [Here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#strtotime) is the reference, with an example, and [the PHP reference of strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php).

Comment: Jost, why don't you turn this into an answer?

Comment: @lorenz: Because I'm too lazy to make a real answer with a code snippet from it. If you want to do it, have a go.

Comment: Thank you.
It runs perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As [Jost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752701/jost) said, it will work with a strtotime stdWrap.

```
lib.kalenderwoche = COA
lib.kalenderwoche {
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
    data = date:U
    strtotime = next Monday
    strftime = %d.%m.%Y
  }
}
```